# NSTextField, Change text in Swift

Tags: swift, nstextfield

I can't seem to be able to change the text Label in a Mac app that I am trying to make.
I am using swift. Here is the code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet var sumlab: NSTextField!
sumlab.text = "\(result.sum)"     // result.sum is the result of a function I made
// I also tried this:
sumlab.text("\(result.sum)")
// and this:
sumlab.insertText("\(result.sum)")
```

None of these seem to work and this is the only problem I need to solve to finish my program.
P.S. when i write sumlab.text it says NSTextField does not have a member named text

Answer (score 62, accepted):

NSTextField is different from a UITextField. It doesn't have a `text` property. It does however inherit from NSControl which has a stringValue property.

```
sumlab.stringValue = "\(result.sum)"
```