# How to use .isempty in OS X swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I am new to Swift, and I'm trying to make a login program for Mac OS X.  I do know about Swift programming on iOS, but I don't know that much about OS X Swift. So I wrote a program for OS X. I almost finished it, but I need to know how to check whether the text fields are empty or not. In iOS, you can do this using the .isempty property. It doesn’t work on OS X though. How can I do this?

```
class InsideViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userNametext: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordtext: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet var conformpasswordtext: NSSecureTextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: NSButton) {
        let userName = userNametext.stringValue
        let userPassword = passwordtext.stringValue
        let userPasswordcon = conformpasswordtext.stringValue

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userName, forKey: "username")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userPassword, forKey: "userpassword")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        if (userNametext.isempty)
    }

}
```

Comment: "but I need to know how to check whether the text fields are empty or not. In iOS, you can do this using the .isempty property" No. `.isEmpty` tells you whether a _string_ is empty, not whether a text field is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if userNametext.stringValue == "" {
    //Action
}
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536572/nstextfield-change-text-in-swift) you can access the text of the NSTextField using the `stringValue` property, which can also be used to modify the text.